# I need help to create a graph with gnuplot

Tags: linux, graph, gnuplot, bandwidth, linux-mint

I am having trouble to figure out how to use gnuplot. I am trying to make a graph with bandwidth over time. I have a script that saves my bandwith, time and date every minute to a log.txt file 
**Example:**

```
47.05 
18:59:40 
12/27/18
47.02 
19:01:02 
12/27/18
47.04 
19:02:25 
12/27/18
46.12 
19:03:47 
12/27/18
46.19 
19:05:08 
12/27/18
```

I want to use that log.txt file to make my graph.
On the x-axis i want the time and on the y-axis i want the bandwidth in Mbps.

I have tried something out but i miss information/knowledge to complete it.

**Example:**

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/gnuplot
  2 reset
  3
  4 set xdata time
  5 set timefmt "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
  6 set format x "%T"
  7
  8 set xlabel "Tijd"
  9 set ylabel "Bandbreedte"
 10
 11 set title "Een grafiek van de bandbreedte in functie van de tijd"
 12
 13 plot "/home/student/log.txt" using 1:2
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I would suggest to reformat your script that it would save the output in columns with tabulation or space as separator. Right now you need to write a script that will extract every 1/3 2/3 3/3 line from the file and feed it to plot.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 1):

as @Kamil Cuk suggested, a different format of your data would be better. You might want to change your logger-program's output (if you can) or use another tool to reformat your data.

However, you can also use some (a bit strange) workaround to reformat your data with gnuplot.
A format like the following wouldbe easier to handle with gnuplot.

```
12/27/18 18:59:40 47.05
12/27/18 19:01:02 47.02
```

The script below reformats is like this and then you can easily plot it.

```
### reformat some logging data
reset session

$Data <<EOD
47.05 
18:59:40 
12/27/18
47.02 
19:01:02 
12/27/18
47.04 
19:02:25 
12/27/18
46.12 
19:03:47 
12/27/18
46.19 
19:05:08 
12/27/18
EOD

# reformat your input data
a = b = c = NaN
set table $Data2
    plot $Data u (c=b,b=a,a=stringcolumn(1),a):(b):(c) with table
unset table
set table $Data3
    plot $Data2 u (stringcolumn(1).' '.stringcolumn(2)):3 every 3::2 with table
unset table

set xdata time
set xtics rotate
set format x "%H:%M"
set timefmt "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"

plot $Data3 u 1:3 w lp lt 7 lc rgb "red"
### end of code
```

This will result in:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here a variant of the nice solution from @theozh above:

First using awk to reformat the input data:

```
awk '{a=$0;getline;b=$0;getline;printf "%s %s,%s",$1,b,a;print ""}' in.txt > out.txt
```

The data looks like this then:

```
12/27/18 18:59:40 ,47.05 
12/27/18 19:01:02 ,47.02 
12/27/18 19:02:25 ,47.04 
12/27/18 19:03:47 ,46.12 
12/27/18 19:05:08 ,46.19
```

With these plot commands:

```
set term png
set output "out.png"
set timefmt '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'
set xdata time
set xtics rotate
set datafile separator ","
plot "out.txt" using 1:2 with linespoint
```

you get this result:

[image: plot]

Comment: thank you, that looks great. Underneath i posted how i make my log.txt file is there a way to rewrite that so i can skip the "awk '{a=$0;getline;b=$0;getline;printf "%s %s,%s",$1,b,a;print ""}' in.txt > out.txt" line?
i am trying to get a result with only 2 scripts and no other actions.